# array of numbers that starts from 0 and ends with the number equal to the number length of n

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How can I create an array of numbers that starts from 0 and ends with the number equal to the number length of n?

ex>
n=1
output:
123456789
n=2
output:
12345...99

Comment: Why does n=1 output 123456789?

Comment: I assume n is amount of digits. Could just use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like `.map((value, index) => index)`.

Comment: sorry! sould be: n=1 output: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] the length of n will be the length of the digits in the array

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` doesn't start with zero. The question text claims it should, yet the examples don't show zero at the start.

Comment: @JavaScript map over *what*? The input is a number.

Comment: @VLAZ ','.repeat(Math.pow(10, 2) - 1).split(',').map((value, index) => index). Assuming zero is part of it.

Comment: @JavaScript good, sounds like an answer. Although splitting is a bit roundabout.

Comment: `[...Array(Math.pow(10, 2) - 1).keys()].map((value, index) => index)` is what you want.

Comment: @JavaScript thank you! though this solution will leave out the last two digits, so n=2 will give: [1,2...98]

Comment: Solved it with adding a +1 in the end so: 

[...Array(Math.pow(10  , 5) - 1).keys()].map((value, index) => index +1)
Thank you so much @JavaScript for the help and to everyone else : )

Answer (score 1):

Finished version of @JavaScript suggestion in the comments.

1. Generate an empty array using [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)
2. Remove the last item since we do not display `0`
3. Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to return an array with the `index` parameter plus 1 (=no `0`).

```js
/***
* n=number of digits
*/
function xyz(n){
  return Array.from({length: Math.pow(10, n) - 1}, (value, index) => index + 1)
};

console.log(xyz(1))
console.log(xyz(2))
```

*Edited due to the comments provided.*

Comment: I approve of this.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple loop

Determine the max value which is where each digit is a nine and there as many digits as `n`. Then loop and create an array with the values:

```js
function fn(n) {
  const min = 1;
  const max = Number("9".repeat(n));
  
  const arr = [];
  for(let i = min; i <= max; i++)
    arr.push(i);
    
  return arr;
}

const singleDigit = fn(1);
const twoDigit = fn(2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(singleDigit));
console.log(JSON.stringify(twoDigit));
```

```html
<h1>See browser console for better view of the logged values</h1>
```

### Using generators and iterators

A more generic solution can be done using generators. A single `generate()` function can handle creating an infinite amount of digits. This can then be limited to an upper bound with generic utility functions. This creates an iterator that will supply values from `min` to `max` and this can be converted to an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Some implementations:

#### `take`

Take a set amount of items from an iterator:

```js
function* generate(start, step = 1) {
  for(let i = start;; i+= step)
    yield i;
}

function* take(num, iterator) {
  for (const item of iterator) {
    if (--num < 0)
      break;
      
    yield item;
  }
}

function fn(n) {
  const min = 1;
  const max = Number("9".repeat(n));
  
  const iterator = take(
    max,
    generate(min)
  );
  
  return Array.from(iterator);
}

const singleDigit = fn(1);
const twoDigit = fn(2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(singleDigit));
console.log(JSON.stringify(twoDigit));
```

```html
<h1>See browser console for better view of the logged values</h1>
```

#### `takeUntil`

Take items from an iterator until a condition is satisfied then stop:

```js
function* generate(start, step = 1) {
  for(let i = start;; i+= step)
    yield i;
}

function* takeUntil(predicate, iterator) {
  for (const item of iterator) {
    yield item;
    if (predicate(item))
      break;
  }
}

function fn(n) {
  const min = 1;
  const max = Number("9".repeat(n));
  
  const iterator = takeUntil(
    x => x >= max,
    generate(min)
  );
  
  return Array.from(iterator);
}

const singleDigit = fn(1);
const twoDigit = fn(2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(singleDigit));
console.log(JSON.stringify(twoDigit));
```

```html
<h1>See browser console for better view of the logged values</h1>
```

#### `takeWhile`

Only take values from an iterator while a condition is satisfied, stop as soon as it is not:

```js
function* generate(start, step = 1) {
  for(let i = start;; i+= step)
    yield i;
}

function* takeWhile(predicate, iterator) {
  for (const item of iterator) {
    if (!predicate(item))
      break;
      
    yield item;
  }
}

function fn(n) {
  const min = 1;
  const max = Number("9".repeat(n));
  
  const iterator = takeWhile(
    x => x <= max,
    generate(min)
  );
  
  return Array.from(iterator);
}

const singleDigit = fn(1);
const twoDigit = fn(2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(singleDigit));
console.log(JSON.stringify(twoDigit));
```

```html
<h1>See browser console for better view of the logged values</h1>
```

#### For more information

See on MDN:

- [Generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)
- [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)
- [Iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)